# Labeling values returned from API

Tags: c#

This method returns a `bool` and a `string` -

```
public (bool active, string name) Report() 
{
}
```

From my controller, I call it like this -

```
public IActionResult Credit([FromBody] Data data)
{
    return Ok(Report())
}
```

The response I get is something like this -

```
{
    "item1": false,
    "item2": "Your name"
}
```

How do I get this response instead -

```
{
    "Active": false,
    "Name": "Your name"
}
```

Comment: Simple answer: do not use value tuples for public APIs. And it is better not to use anonymous types for it as well. Declare a model and return it. In this case you will have a well-defined, reusable, type-safe model with self-explanatory name

Comment: The keys of a ValueTuple cannot be returned from a web API, there limited. Create an object and return this.

Comment: *Don't* use tuples. Return an anonymous type

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The quick and easy way would be to return an anonymous type, taking the values from the returned tuple

```
public IActionResult Credit([FromBody] Data data) 
{
    //...
    var report = Report();
    return Ok(new 
    {
        Active = report.active,
        Name = report.name
    })
}
```

Ideally you should return a strongly typed model that can be returned from the API

```
public class ReportModel 
{
    public string Name { get;set; }
    public bool Active { get;set; }
}
```

and update accordingly

```
public ReportModel Report()  
{
    //...
}

public IActionResult Credit([FromBody] Data data) 
{
    //...
    var report = Report();
    return Ok(report);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Value tuples (as you are using for the return from your `Report()` method) are just syntactic sugar around a `ValueTuple<T,T,...,T>` object. Therefore, the real property names are not `active` and `name` but, in fact, `item1` and `item2`.

So your method gets converted to something like this:

```
[return: TupleElementNames(new string[] {
    "active",
    "name"
})]
public ValueTuple<bool, string> Report()
```

---

How do you resolve this? You should create a model that reflects what you want to return:

```
public class ActiveName
{
    public string Name { get;set;}
    public bool Active {get;set;}
}
```

and then change your method to return this `ActiveName` type.

Another way is to return an anonymous type as dynamic, but I recommend against this approach since using `dynamic` introduces the potential for runtime errors if mistakes are made. If you're just using it to return from your API method, then it's probably OK.

```
public dynamic Report()
{
    return new { name = "abc", active = true };
}
```

Comment: `"are just syntactic sugar around the regular Tuple<T,T,...,T> object."` -- This is flat out wrong

Comment: do you know the difference between a `struct` and a `class`?

Comment: @John https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

```
public IActionResult Credit([FromBody] Data data)
{
   var x = Report();
   return Ok(new {Active = x.Item1, UserName = x.Item2});
}
```